# USB data lines: current consumption

Tags: usb, current, termination

I am designing a USB device and I can't find easily the USB specs about the maximum current consumption allowed for the D+ and D- lines.

I am planning to use a 39Ω termination resistor on this lines, and the ones I find in resistor networks of 2 are 0603 62.5mW. If I assume a 3.3V connected to a short to GND (improbable, but maybe good practice to make a more reliable system) this will be (3.3 / 39) * 3.3 = 297mW. So if I can estimate the maximum current consumption of this lines, I might check if 63.5mW are fine or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the USB 2.0 specification, a host or device transceiver is required to survive a short of D+ or D- to either GND, or VBUS, or the cable shielding, or each other for at least 24 hours. It is also advised to survive it indefinitely.
Therefore you should calculate with a current of at least 5.25V/whatever impedance you calculate for your part. Also, consider the fact that a 125mW resistor dissipating 125mW will produce a dT of about 100 degrees Celsius, which is probably undesired.

The specification also states the required impedance of a full-speed-only driver to be between 28 and 44 ohms, and of a high-speed driver to be between 40.5 and 49.5 ohms.

Comment: This will still require a 0,7W resistor, which is impractical, is this really how people terminate USB lines? I could use a polyfuse in the MCU, but still, I think a proper resistor is a better way to solve it.

Comment: Most hosts that support decent USB survival to the short circuit test implement chips that install on the host side and have internal over current detection. That can result in the chip switching off the 5V feed to the USB connector. Using resistors to limit the current is not the best solution.

Comment: @mFeinstein: I think a sane implementation would involve the output driver of the transceiver limiting the current flowing to/from the data lines to some feasible value (increasing Rdson when overloaded). And that would mean you don't need such a high power resistor there.

Comment: I am using an Atmel UC3, I am not sure it has an overcurrent detection over the USB interface.