# USB Data Line Current Value

Tags: usb, low-power, termination

I am designing USB2.0 hardware input but i don't have enough space on my PCB area. I searched many site but I cant find any information about D+ D- data lines power consumption. I am using 15R termination resistor. 0402 package power is enough for this? or how can I calculate the power value of the resistors.

[image]

Comment: Not sure how to calculate the exact power rating needed, but I've used 0402 in similar usages without any issues.

Comment: Hi @Klas-Kenny thank you for information :)

Comment: Take a look here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/84580/usb-data-lines-current-consumption

Comment: If you are designing USB2.0 Full-speed interface, the lines are not terminated (actual termination is 15k), so the dissipated power is rather small. If you are designing for High-Speed mode, the 15R will likely kill the entire functionality of your interface.